# karma-jasmine Cannot read property 'clearTimeout'

Tags: javascript, karma-runner, karma-jasmine

I can't seem to get **karma-jasmine** working.

If I run `karma start` I get this error:

> Chrome 37.0.2062 (Windows 8.1) ERROR   Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read
>   property 'clearTimeout' of undefined   at
>   [censored]/node_modules/karma-jasmine/lib/jasmine.js:1826

This is my config file built with `karma init`.

I've modified the files, logging, and single run fields

```
module.exports = function(config) {
  config.set({

    // base path that will be used to resolve all patterns (eg. files, exclude)
    basePath: '',


    // frameworks to use
    // available frameworks: https://npmjs.org/browse/keyword/karma-adapter
    frameworks: ['jasmine'],


    // list of files / patterns to load in the browser
    files: [
        'test/jasmine/jasminetest.html',

        'lib/bower/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js',
        'lib/bower/jasmine/lib/jasmine-core/jasmine.js',
        'lib/bower/jasmine/lib/jasmine-core/jasmine-html.js',
        'lib/bower/jasmine/lib/jasmine-core/boot.js',

        'bin/request.min.js',
        'test/jasmine/specs/request/request.js'
    ],


    // list of files to exclude
    exclude: [
    ],


    // preprocess matching files before serving them to the browser
    // available preprocessors: https://npmjs.org/browse/keyword/karma-preprocessor
    preprocessors: {
    },


    // test results reporter to use
    // possible values: 'dots', 'progress'
    // available reporters: https://npmjs.org/browse/keyword/karma-reporter
    reporters: ['progress'],


    // web server port
    port: 9876,


    // enable / disable colors in the output (reporters and logs)
    colors: true,


    // level of logging
    // possible values: config.LOG_DISABLE || config.LOG_ERROR || config.LOG_WARN || config.LOG_INFO || config.LOG_DEBUG
    logLevel: config.LOG_DEBUG,


    // enable / disable watching file and executing tests whenever any file changes
    autoWatch: false,


    // start these browsers
    // available browser launchers: https://npmjs.org/browse/keyword/karma-launcher
    browsers: ['Chrome'],


    // Continuous Integration mode
    // if true, Karma captures browsers, runs the tests and exits
    singleRun: true
  });
};
```

Here is the function it seems to be choking on

```
jasmine.getGlobal().clearTimeout = function(timeoutKey) {
  if (jasmine.Clock.installed.clearTimeout.apply) {
     return jasmine.Clock.installed.clearTimeout.apply(this, arguments);
  } else {
    return jasmine.Clock.installed.clearTimeout(timeoutKey);
  }
};
```

Is there anything that stands out wrong here? Everything else I've done is stock install work via nodejs.

Answer (score 1):

I feel plenty useless right now. The problem was due to re-loading the jasmine files in the files field (in addition to frameworks)

The solution was to delete

```
    'lib/bower/jasmine/lib/jasmine-core/jasmine.js',
    'lib/bower/jasmine/lib/jasmine-core/jasmine-html.js',
    'lib/bower/jasmine/lib/jasmine-core/boot.js',
```

Comment: Thank you, I did the same thing... I feel useless as well :)